# findFirst where relation count is greater than zero

Tags: typescript, nestjs, prisma

In this simple query, how can I add `gt` to select all `subCategories` when count of `menu` is greater than zero?

```js
return await this.prisma.category.findFirst({
  where: {
    id: categoryId,
  },
  include: {
    subCategories: {
      include: {
        menu: true,
      },
    },
  },
});
```

This query returns all menus, even menus that have a count of zero.

Comment: Add `where: { menu: { count: { gt: 0 } } }` to `subCategories` according to the [docs](https://www.prisma.io/docs/concepts/components/prisma-client/filtering-and-sorting#filter-conditions-and-operators).

Answer (score 0):

```
return await this.prisma.category.findFirst({
where: {
id: categoryId,
},
include: {
subCategories: {
  include: {
    menu: {
      where: {
        count: {
          gt: 0
        }
       }
      }
     }
    }
   }
 });
```

This section of the code is telling the DB to include related menu nodes when retrieving sub nodes, it will only get the menu nodes if the counter is larger than 0 (gt: 0), filtering the out-sub nodes menu with empty menu.

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**

Answer (score 0):

Currently you can't filter based on a relation's count because it isn't yet supported by prisma. However, for this specific use-case, the closest you can achieve would be to filter on `subCategories` that has **at least** one `menu`. For this you add a filter `none` on `menu`, like the following:

```javascript
return await this.prisma.category.findFirst({
  where: {
    id: categoryId,
  },
  include: {
    subCategories: {
      NOT: {
        menu: {
          none: {} // subCategories that *does* have posts
        },
      },
    },
  },
});
```

You can find more about this [here in this feature request](https://github.com/prisma/prisma/issues/3821)